# Javascript global array turns to undefined for no reason

Tags: javascript, global-variables

In my web pages I have 2 lists of items which are loaded from DB. To decrease traffic I store all items loaded from DB in global array and when the user searches the list, I search the array first and only when the item is not found I go to the DB.

So at first I define my global array at  the top of my script and only once.

```
var _navArr=[];
```

And then I want to access it with this code

```
$.ajax({   //At breakpoint here the _navArr is defined and full of items
    type: "POST",
    url: "Webservices/ws_publikace.svc/ws_getUserNavigatorList",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
           //But inside success function _navArr is undefined
           _navArr[navArr] = extedItemArr(_navArr[navArr], msg.d);
            }
});
```

But it doesn't work as described in the code.

Any Idea why is it so? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `_navArr` is actually visible from the `success` function?

Comment: I would say that `_navArr` is either overridden or deleted somewhere after the call to `$.ajax()`.

Comment: What does `extedItemArr` do?

Comment: Do you have another variable declaration `var _navArr;` in your function?

Comment: Show *all* of your code, not an excerpt that masks the problem. Put it in a fiddle so people can see the problem in action.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist the function just takes all items from first argument and join them with the items from second argument and then returns the final array, so there shouldn't be problem

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I've tried, but it's impossible, because it's part of very complicated procedure

Comment: @wared +1, you motivated me to go through the whole process and I have found out, that sometimes is the array being set to undefined, depending on how long does the ajax call take.

Answer (score 0):

Instead `var _navArr=[];` try `window._navArr = [];`